# NHibernate very fast collection access required

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate

I have a main User table which when mapped through NHibernate constructs a large hierachy of associated data comprising the full user details which I only need very rarely so don't always load that. I have a partial table as well called UserLight which only contains the very basic information and no hierachichal joins or collections for the many times I require basic information accessed rapidly.

But my question is aside from those, that is just background.

My website involves searching other users from a large userbase and I want to provide the functionality to remove people from your searches, ie you click an X on the users profile and it adds them to a list of removals that will not appear in future searches.

I have created a separate table and object mapping called UserSearchRemoval with just UserId, RemovedId as data columns.

I am trying to figure out the best way to work with this from the code, as I want responsivity to be high. I imagine the best way GUI wise is to call an Ajax query on the web side that calls into a webservice, passing in the two user id's, which then does the work at the database level.

What I'm not sure on is the best way to do this at the DB level. On a basic level I could just check to see if the search removal already exists (takes time) and if not, add it, or I could just add it without the check and risk duplicates which wouldnt be an issue I suppose, just not the cleanest solution. So just adding it would appear to be the fastest method.

Is there another method I could do this by maintaining a session level list of the users removals and just adding to that and having NHibernate do the rest? This to me sounds bad by holding loads of data at session level and the effort to update the collection in memory and transfer that to db objects sounds like it would be much slower than just adding a single row to the DB.

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "remove user from search", do you mean that once a user is removed from a search, if this search is done again that user will not appear, or is the removal valid just for the time of the search (+paging or sorting may be) ?

Comment: can you provide some information about your mappings? is `UserSearchRemoval` mapped to an entity or a collection property on `User`?

Comment: At the moment UserSearchRemoval is a standalone entity, there is no way to retrieve it other than session.Query<UserSearchRemoval>().Where(u => u.UserId == userId). I thought about making it a collection on User but as it could be a very large table in time, every time you wanted to pull back UserDetails it would be doing that join and slowing things down immensely, so I kept it separate. Also the search feature is the primary feature of the site and is the part that needs to be most performant so I kept it separate to optimise that one use case

Comment: Skyp - see below for explanation of how it should work. Once you remove them, they will never again appear in your searches as long as you're a member of the site. You will be able to review your removed list and re-add users to search if you made a mistake but that will hardly ever be used. Imagine a dating site where once you decide you arent interested in someone, you click an X and they will never be shown to you again in your searches to make your searches easier to find new users you haven't assessed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the relative sizes of your user database, average search result and average block list.
It also depends on the way blocking rules might not get more complex in the future, making it safe to include them at the DB level.

Assuming your user db is 500 000 users, your average search result is 500 and the average block list is 100, and that the rules might evolve, I would go for a dictionnary based post-search application-level filtering.

Comment: The volumes the site needs to handle are potentially 500k to a million users, each who may have anything from 0-5000 users in the blocked list depending on that users way of operating. The way it should work is that once a user is removed from your searches they will not appear in this or any future searches, so they are removed permanently from your search. I haven't even thought about the actual search yet, I assume I'll just calculate the set of search results, load the blocked list separately and filter the original results before returning them to the user.

Comment: @user1122909 with 5000 users, doing a post-search filter might not be the most efficient and scalable solution. Anyway you will have to check that in your blocking table index blockingUserId/blockedUserId (in this exact order) is THE clustered index

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on a more efficient and scalable solution given these volumes? Also making it the clustered index.... with potentially 2 billion rows at it's peak, adding a single user to search results would result in re-physical ordering of the entire table! Surely that would be a site-breaking performance hit?

Comment: @user1122909 I guess the index reorganization problem would be addressed by tuning the fill factor ( though I never had to consider 2 billion rows ) Seems like your question would get much better answers on http://dba.stackexchange.com/